# Is one culpable for transgressing shabbos if he is having a mental breakdown

Tags: halacha, shabbat, melacha-creative-work, pikuachnefesh-danger-life, psych-mentalhealth

Over the years I've heard and seen people who were smoking on shabbos, but I noticed they were clearly having a mental breakdown. I would say maybe even outwardly displaying suicidal emotions.

Are they culpable for going to measures of self medicating. Is this pikuach nefesh.

Does a person have to have daas to transgress shabbos?
There's clearly no daas here. So I guess it wouldn't apply.

Comment: Mental breakdown is unclear. There is no treatment without transgressing Shabbat ?

Comment: I realize this is a theoretical question about the limits of piquach nefesh, but on a practical level, the stuff discussed in this thread can overcome even the worsr cravings: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/120943/kashrut-status-of-certain-oral-tobacco-products-during-pesach

Answer (score 1):

The Mishna says clearly one is not violating shabbos to extinguish a light that is threatening someone with a severe mental illness.

A person themselves who is not in their right mind, as you said, is not held liable.

But let's be careful with overexpanding the term. A nicotine addict having withdrawal cravings is not "crazy", and "self-medicating" is not the answer. (The whole point of breaking shabbos to save a life is to in fact *save* them, not just keep making things worse.)

Comment: It's definitely a CYLOR case, so I don't really think one should give a general answer...