Are nicotine pouches permitted on fast days?
Are nicotine pouches such as Zyn permitted to be used on fast days? These pouches are tucked between ones lip or cheek and gums and the nicotine is absorbed into their bloodstream through the mucous membranes in the mouth. Are they similar to nicotine patches? Or are pouches assur because they are placed into the mouth?

https://www.webmd.com/smoking-cessation/nicotine-pouches

How is this any different from chewing gum? On the plus side, though, they are totally permitted on Shabbat

Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/120943/kashrut-status-of-certain-oral-tobacco-products-during-pesach

https://shulchanaruchharav.com/halacha/8-general-laws-and-restrictions/ mentions chewig tobacco and spitting
